# Basic error of seperate class in polymorphism. C++

Tags: c++

Aaand im back again with my second question and im kinda not sure about wether i should have posted all the seperate classes cuz it looks somewhat long. And im sure the solution is pretty small.
Anyways, i am at polymorphism tutorial vid that i am following and everything works fine if i follow it and put all classes in "main.cpp". But when i tried to do the same program with seperate classes (seen below) i am getting error "

> *E:\Codeblocks\Poly\main.cpp|11|error: cannot convert 'Ninja*' to 'Enemy*' in initialization|".*

I kinda understand what the error is saying..i think.. but dont know what i did wrong since the same code was working when Enemy and Ninja class wasnt seperate but now as seperate classes its not working. I think i included those classes properly in main.cpp.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
    #include "Enemy.h"
    #include "Ninja.h"
    #include "Monster.h"


int main()
{
    Ninja n;
    Monster m;
    Enemy *enemy1=&n;
    Enemy *enemy2=&m;
    enemy1->setAttackPower(20);
    enemy2->setAttackPower(50);
    n.attack();
    m.attack();
    return 0;
}
```

Enemy.h

```
#ifndef ENEMY_H
#define ENEMY_H


class Enemy
{
    public:
        Enemy();
        void setAttackPower(int a);


    protected:
        int attackPower;

    private:
};

#endif // ENEMY_H
```

Enemy.cpp

```
#include "Enemy.h"


Enemy::Enemy()
{
    //ctor
}

void Enemy::setAttackPower(int a)
{
    attackPower=a;
};
```

Ninja.h

```
#ifndef NINJA_H
#define NINJA_H



class Ninja
{
    public:
        Ninja();
        void attack();

    protected:

    private:
};

#endif // NINJA_H
```

Ninja.cpp

```
#include "Ninja.h"
#include <iostream>


Ninja::Ninja()
{
    //ctor
}

void Ninja::attack(){
std::cout<<" I am a ninja. Ninja chop! -"<<attackPower<<"\n";}
```

Comment: "not sure about wether i should have posted all the seperate classes".... read about [mcve]. Complete means: all code necessary to reproduce the error. Minimal means: not more than what is necessary

Comment: Well a `Ninja` is not an `Enemy` type.

Comment: Ah sry. My bad. Will do next time

Comment: are you sure that error message and code are without typos? Because errror says "cannot convert 'Ninja'..." but in code you try to assign a `Ninja*` to an `Enemy*`

Comment: @tobi303 Compiler doesn't know how to cast `Ninja` to `Enemy`, since `Ninja` is not derived from `Enemy`. That's all. Error message is correct.

Comment: I am pretty sure that code and error are without typos. Actually i have another Monster class too but i didsnt post it cuz its same as Ninja class.
||=== Build: Debug in Poly (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
E:\Codeblocks\Poly\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
E:\Codeblocks\Poly\main.cpp|11|error: cannot convert 'Ninja*' to 'Enemy*' in initialization|
E:\Codeblocks\Poly\main.cpp|12|error: cannot convert 'Monster*' to 'Enemy*' in initialization|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

this is full error shown actually

Comment: Please add your last comment to your question. Its hard to read as a comment.

Comment: the error message in your comment says "cannot convert 'Ninja*' to 'Enemy*'" which is different from the one is the question

Comment: the reason is that in your question the * in `Ninja*` got swallowed by the formatting stuff. I just checked by pressing "edit" and looking at the raw text

Comment: @PavelPájaHalbich there is no attempt to cast a `Ninja` to an `Enemy*` in the code.

Comment: @ Everyone Im sorry for the jumbled up texts. Kinda new at this site and programming so forgive me for not being as clear as i would have liked to be.
Anyways i got the answer now and as i thought it was a silly mistake.
Thanks a lot to everyone for the fast response. :):)

Comment: @tobi303 Ah, now I get your complaints. You are right, I'm sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your `Ninja` class is not inhereted from `Enemy` class. You must define Ninja class like this:

```
#include "Enemy.h"

class Ninja : public Enemy
{
    public:
        Ninja();
        void attack();

    protected:

    private:
};
```

EDIT: I added #include directive. Without it compiler won't know, where to find `Enemy` class declaration.

Comment: Ahh i needed to use composition too?!! This works. Thanks a lot. lol i knew solution was simple just didnt cross my mind cuz i was too focused just putting the original tutorial vid to seperate classes. :(

Comment: @Sanrai Since I'm not a native speaker, I don't know, if this is called *composition*. If you mean this (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), then you are mistaken and Composition over Inheritance is different OOP approach. As far as I know, you are dealing only with Inheretance. 
And if I may point to another good OOP practice - you should declare your **attack** method as virtual `virtual void Enemy::Attack(..)`. Then all of your enemies can "do" attack and each of them can do it differently.

Comment: Me neither :)
And wow that link got a lot of code and i  dont understand at all. Anyways i am just watching basic c++ tutorials..and i meant https://thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=16&video=17522  for composition.
Oh Virtual function is the next video after this. But i think i will stop here for today. Got to process all the things i have learnt for the past few days.

Comment: You might try: `Enemy *enemy2=static_cast<Enemy*>(&m);`, and then make all of your required methods `virtual`

Comment: @MateoConLechuga Assuming that inheritance is corrected, Why do you propose using `static_cast` in this beautiful case of **implicit** cast?